# Spring - No default constructor found

Tags: java, spring

I have a class which looks like this:

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
```

and I also have a test class which looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    MyServiceImpl.class})
...
```

I get this exception:

```
 Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire 
field: private org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate 
myPackage.MyServiceImpl.simpMessagingTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Does anyone know what I can do in order to get it work, SimpMessagingTemplate does not have a default constructor.

Comment: You title does not fit to the error mesage.

Comment: Which spring Version do you use?

Comment: @YCF_L Why OP should remove private? It is allowed to use spring beans as private variables

Comment: The classes list of `@ConfigurationContext` should contains classes which are annotated as `@Configuration`

Comment: Plaese add the complete stacktrace and read https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html. There you see that tis class has no Default constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpMessagingTemplate` seems to have either no default constructor or is not annotated with `@Component` (or `@Service` or another sub-class of `@Component`); or both.
Please check that a default constructor is available and the class is configured to be a Spring bean.

Comment: May I ask to accept the answer in case it was helpful?

Answer (score -1):

Its not related to missing constructor, but Spring fails to find proper bean to inject into your test class,

Two options to solve it as I see

1. @ContextConfiguration(classes = {
   MyServiceImpl.class, SimpMessagingTemplate.class})
2. Add @mock SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate; to your test class

Comment: SimpMessagingTemplate.class would need a default constructor

Comment: How MyServiceImpl is a configuration class?